# What does an idiosyncratic solution in radicals means?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, radicals

I read that Galois theory asserts that some equations of at least degree 5 don't have an idiosyncratic solution in radicals.

So, what does this statement actually means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiosyncratic means unique to an individual.

This is a quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function)

```
Solving quintic equations in terms of radicals was a major problem
in algebra, from the 16th century, when cubic and quartic equations
were solved, until the first half of the 19th century, when the
impossibility of such a general solution was proved
(Abel–Ruffini theorem).
```

All $n^\text{th}$-degree polynomials with rational coefficients have $n$ roots. The question was, can these roots be written as radical expressions. The hope was that, if the expression was complicated enough, you could. It turned out that, for $n \ge 5$, sometimes you can't.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP found the idiosyncratic wording in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation (in the last sentence in the History section).